# Stable splitting of $\Omega SU(n)$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, loop-spaces

The space $\Omega SU(n)$ is homotopy-equivalent to $SL_n(\mathbb{C}[z,z^{-1}])/SL_n(\mathbb{C}[z])$.  Using this, Steve Mitchell introduced a filtration of $\Omega SU(n)$ by subspaces $F_k$ which can be viewed as Schubert varieties ([MR0862881](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=862881)).   The homology ring is $H_*(\Omega SU(n))=\mathbb{Z}[b_1,\dotsc,b_{n-1}]$, with $|b_i|=2i$, and $H_*(F_k)$ is just the subspace spanned by monomials $b^\alpha=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}b_i^{\alpha_i}$ with $\sum_i\alpha_i\leq k$.  It was apparently conjectured by Hopkins and Mahowald that this filtration is stably split, so $\Sigma^\infty \Omega SU(n)_+\simeq\bigvee_k\Sigma^\infty F_k/F_{k-1}$.  A later paper of Mark Mahowald and Bill Richter ([MR0862881](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1136478)) stated that there was an article in press written by Richter, titled *A partial Cartan formula for the stable splitting of $\Omega SU(n)$, and a
stable splitting of the loops on a infinite complex Stiefel manifold*, containing a proof of the conjecture.  However, no such article ever appeared.  I vaguely remember that there was some discussion of this situation in the late 1990s, but I do not remember the contents of any such discussions.  Has there been more recent work on this question?

Comment: It seems that the real and quaternionic analogues of this result are proven in Crabb and Mitchell's paper _The loops on $U(n)/O(n)$ and $U(2n)/Sp(n)$_ ([MR0938454](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0938454)).

Comment: Crabb's paper [On the stable splitting of $U(n)$ and $\Omega U(n)$](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0082999) is even older, but is quite beautiful. A more recent paper is Greg Arone's [The Mitchell-Richter Filtration of Loops on Stiefel Manifolds Stably Splits ](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2668928).

Comment: A paper I wrote with Yuan https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0001870819301525 proves a highly structured version of this splitting

Comment: @JeremyHahn if you want to make that comment an answer, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A paper I wrote with Allen Yuan [Multiplicative structure in the stable splitting of $\Omega SL_n(\mathbb{C})$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0001870819301525) proves a highly structured version of this splitting.